# Python: assert call to a list that contains a variable

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

This question follows python 2.7.3 syntax. In unittest framework, suppose I have the following set up:

```
import mock;
my_mock = mock.Mock();
my_patch = mock.patch("my_method", my_mock);
```

Now suppose my_method takes on a list argument as input.

How Can I use my_mock.assert_any_call to make sure that a call is made to my_method such that the input list contains a particular value?

Comment: Are you still interested about this question?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by use both [`mock_calls`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.mock_calls) and call unpacking as documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#call). Now a for cycle can be enough to do the work:

```
>>> import mock
>>> m = mock.Mock()
>>> m([1,2])
<Mock name='mock()' id='140596484020816'>
>>> m([5,6])
<Mock name='mock()' id='140596484020816'>
>>> m([8,9])
<Mock name='mock()' id='140596484020816'>
>>> for name,args,kwrgs in m.mock_calls:
...     if 5 in args[0]:
...         print("found")
... 
found
```